# Cutting out shapes with Boolean Difference

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to cut out several identical complex holes from a sphere. (I want a spherical hole, with a beveled edge and slices in the rim). So I've made a negative of the complex hole (a sphere with  cone and two planks.) and **JOIN**ed it all together. Now I can place it wherever I want and cut multiple identical holes.

I move my cutout into position within the large sphere, select the large sphere, then **Modify > Boolean > Difference** and choose the cutout. Then I **Apply** it.

It does not seem to cut out the shape. In fact, it even leaves a bit of the smaller shape left over. (I am certain all parts of the negative cutout are joined.)

Obviously, I am doing this wrong. I suspect it has to do with how I made the **JOIN** to make the complex shape.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: 3 screen shots]

Comment: Just for fun, use a Boolean UNION to make the complex shape instead of JOIN? The join creates non-manifold geometry that may be confusing the later Boolean operation.

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying that now. But I can only UNION one object at a time, right? So B > A, *then* C > AB, *then* D > ABC, right?

Comment: Blender Booleans get confused when elements share faces, edges, or vertices.   Not sure if that's contributing, but I find that nudging one of the objects just a bit can solve boolean problems sometimes.